# Na última execução do laço de repetição o valor digitado é atribuído ao meu contador

Tags: c, array, for, alocação

Coloquei um `printf()` para acompanhar o que acontecia e estava tudo normal, até digitar meu último valor e ele ser atribuído para o contador `quantN`. A condicional até funciona quando é um valor negativo, ele adiciona mais um ao valor (-5 vira -4).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0, somaP = 0, quantN = 0, valores[9];

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        printf("Digite o %do valor: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &valores[i]);
            if(valores[i] < 0){
                quantN++;
            } else {
                somaP += valores[i];
            }     
    }

    printf("Soma dos positivos: %d\n", somaP);
    printf("Quantidade de negativos: %d\n", quantN);

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema principal é que está pedindo 10 valores mas está reservando espaço só para 9 no *array*.

É claro que também não tem nenhuma validação do dado digitado então pode acontecer coisas estranhas na execução, porém isso não trará problema se tudo for digitado certo. Não vi necessidade de ter um *array* aí, se tivesse feito isso de forma simples o erro nem aconteceria (a não ser que o exercício peça para imprimir todos os valores digitados depois).

Aproveitei para fazer a condição do `for` de uma forma mais natural para os programadores e modernizei algumas coisas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int somaP = 0, quantN = 0, valores[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Digite o %do valor: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &valores[i]);
        if (valores[i] < 0) quantN++;
        else somaP += valores[i];
    }
    printf("\nSoma dos positivos: %d\n", somaP);
    printf("Quantidade de negativos: %d\n", quantN);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/se826T). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/SumCountc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumCount.c).

Comment: Como o array começa na posição 0 acabou me confundindo, agora entendi como funciona. E usei array porque a lista de exercícios era feita para praticá-lo, então nem parei pra questionar. Muito obrigado por responder a dúvida e me apresentar o código editado, vou começar a usar esse padrão.